# The right usage of 412 http status code ? (REST)

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I would like to know if the HTTP error code `412` is used correctly on our RESTful api.

We have one URL which regenerates some data on request, and it has some logic in the server-side to check internally if there is nothing new to regenerate it will retrieve `412` status code. If there are some changes on server it will regenerate data and it will retrieve `200` status code.

I am thinking that `412` is not a good choice for error, because the condition checking is happening in server-side internally. So I think that using status code `200` for **both** cases would be probably a better approach. Finally the URL would respond with JSON which would contain data about the generation status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precondition failed is definitely misused in the described scenario. It should be used in strict correlation with `if`-family headers, such as: `If-Match` or `If-None-Match`, etc.

Codes that are useable in this case are: 200, 204 and 409.

1. 200 - in both cases (data generated, no generation) and with a meaningful body - data or message that there was no need for generation
2. 200 - when data were generated and 204 when no generation took place.
3. 200 - when data were generated and 409 when no generation took place.

In every case (except 409) you should include a meaningful message or the data itself.

404 won't be useful here - this is not the case that the endpoint wasn't found.